# custom error handler for controller,yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a controller "front" and I want only for this controller to use a custom error action.
How can I do this? I tried [this](http://www.codevoila.com/post/24/how-to-use-yii2-error-handler) but it does not seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to catch the Exception

```
if ($model == null) {
   // (I want the front layout only for this exception,so this 'throw' seems not to working as I want,it has the 'site' layout of site/error default error action )throw new NotFoundHttpException('The patient does not exist.');
            $exception = new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException("The patient does not exist");
            $statusCode = $exception->statusCode;
            $name = $exception->getName();
            $message = $exception->getMessage();
            return $this->render('error', [
                        'exception' => $exception,
                        'statusCode' => $statusCode,
                        'name' => $name,
                        'message' => $message
            ]);
```